# tmux inside Cygwin mintty - unicode characters broken depending on command

Tags: cygwin, tmux, unicode

Please help me understand what's going on with some unicode characters looking right inside mintty + tmux in some command outputs, but not in others.

Sample commands:

```
for c in 00AE 1F007 1F32D 1F603; do printf '%s\t' "$c"; bash -c "echo -e '\U$c'"; done

unicode-list | grep -aPwi '00AE|1F007|1F32D|1F603'

unicode-list | tac | grep -aPwi '00AE|1F007|1F32D|1F603'
```

Here is my Cygwin mintty + zsh without tmux, showing four sample characters correctly:
[image: without tmux]

And here are the same commands inside the same mintty, but inside tmux:
[image: inside tmux]
So, in the first command (`bash echo -e`), character 1F32D got lost. In the second command (`unicode-list` + pipe to `grep`), 1F32D and 1F603 got lost. Add another pipe to `tac` to reverse order, and 00AE may additionally get lost.

Command `unicode-list` is this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# prints UnitCodeData.txt with an additional column containing the actual character.

f=/usr/share/unicode/ucd/UnicodeData.txt
if [ ! -r "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f does not exist or is not readable" >&2
        exit 2
fi

while IFS= read -r line || [ -s "$line" ]; do
        code=${line%;*}
        echo -en "\\U$code;"
        echo "$line"
done < "$f"
```

My configuration:

```
» cygcheck -c tmux
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
tmux                 3.2-0          OK
» locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g prefix F4
bind F4 send-prefix
bind F5 copy-mode
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string '#{pane_title}'
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-bg black
set -g window-status-current-style bg=white,fg=black
set -g window-status-style bg=black,fg=gray

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-yank'

# ______________________________________________________________________
# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

What's going on here?

Comment: from where is coming unicode-list ?

Comment: That script is included in my question. It uses file /usr/share/unicode/ucd/UnicodeData.txt, which is part of Cygwin package unicode-ucd-15.0.0-1.

Comment: confirmed. I suggest you to report it on the user mailing list `cygwin (at) cygwin (dot) com` see also  https://cygwin.com/problems.html